# How to disable IconButton ripple effect in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am having a AppBar with IconButton in it. While hovering the button it shows a oval hover in it . I tried to disable it by giving

`disableFocusRipple={true}`

But it doesnt works.Please help me with that.

[image: Here i am sharing the image of the hover]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might use the property `disableRipple`. if true it will disable the ripple effect. `disableFocusRipple` only works when `disableRipple` is true. But you have a price on that. You loose some state styles. 
Take a look at the API docs. https://material-ui.com/api/button/

Comment: i tried giving this three in IconButton 
                
                disableRipple={true}
                disableFocusRipple={true}
                disableTouchRipple={true}

but this not works for me

Comment: Please, check out this codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-wilbur-ee1yu

Comment: In that example itself by giving , this one..still i can see the ripple. its not removing

   <IconButton
        disableFocusRipple={true}
        disableRipple={true}
        aria-label="delete"
      >
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>

Comment: I don't see it on Chrome, IE and FF. Could you provide your material-ui version? I am using 4.9.5.

Comment: Actually i tried to do that in your codeSandbox example. But i can see the hover after adding this two disableRipple={true} disableFocusRipple={true}.  Mine is 4.8.1

Comment: Hey you need more than just the ripple. You need to remove the style when it is hover. It is another state. In this case put the background as transparent. Check the codepen

Comment: @DhanushKumarS if you get your response. Please, vote it! We are helping to get points. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For some reason none of the `disableRipple` properties has worked for me, but I was able to disable ripple effect on an `IconButton` by just making its hover background colour transparent.

Code:

```
<IconButton className={classes.disableRipple} aria-label="View">
  <InfoIcon/>
</IconButton>
```

Then just style it like so (or any other way you want to style it, can be inline):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  disableRipple: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
  },
}));
```

Comment: This answer is relevant for the current `mui/material` version `^5.0.0`. There seems to be a problem with these two props and a good workaround is to disable it using `backgroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

Ripple is the animation that occurs when clicked or on focus (not by default I think). What you are looking for is the hover background color. You should be able to unset the color by overriding the css:

```
.MuiButtonBase-root:hover {
        background-color: unset;
    }
```